# Knockout binding not updating the table

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a situation where I want to show a table in a dialog box. Content of table will be loaded from data obtained `$.getJSON(<URL>)`
I have in my html the dialog box created with table in it.

My rough code snippet:

HTML:

```
<button id="commitButton" data-bind="click: $root.previewAndCommit.bind()"> Commit Changes</button>
```

Javascript:

```
self.previewAndCommit = function(data, event){
    $("#PACDialog").ojDialog("open");
    self.loadPreviewTable(data.id);  // data.id is fileId
}

self.loadPreviewTable = function(fileId){
$.getJSON(<URL for getting JSON>, function (data) {

self.PACdatasource = new oj.PagingTableDataSource(new oj.ArrayTableDataSource(data, {idAttribute: 'key'}));
        });
    }
```

Now with this code the Table which is using PACdatasource as datasource is not rendering anything. If I am hardcoding any data outside function self.loadPreviewTable then it's rendered in the table.

I am new to knockout and binding concept. Can some please help, what's I am doing wrong with binding. Seems like my binding is not updating the data received from $.getJSON

Please help !!

Comment: The post lacks some essential information. Please try to add enough code to form a [mcve] to the question. At the least I'd expect some `observable` or `observableArray` proprties. If you don't know what those are I suggest doing [the KnockoutJS tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) first and getting back afterwards.

Comment: hi John, can you pleas give more information on the viewmodel you are using (in this case PACdatasource) and how are you binding it to the table node?, this code is not enough to help you

Comment: Hi @JulioCT:
I followed Jeroen's suggestion and read knockout tutorial and found out that I was doing a conceptual silly mistake.

I was initializing my self.PACdatasource = ko.observable();

and then I was setting multiple times as:

self.PACdatasource = new oj.PagingTableDataSource(new oj.ArrayTableDataSource(data, {idAttribute: 'key'}));

which was basically resetting the PACdatasource and it was no more an observable and hence my Table was not updated.

Thanks both of you for taking time for my novice mistake :)